# Check existence of element in a vector of elements

Tags: arrays, matlab

```
vector = [ 11 12 13 14 15 ]
```

is there a function that returns 1 or 0 depending on the existence of vector(6)

there is the `ismember` function for a cell array

also in Python there is the  `in` operator

Is there anything equivalent in MATLAB? Ifso what would it look like?

```
if vector(6) exists
    matrix_A = [ matrix_A, vector(6)]
else
    matrix_A = [ matrix_A, 0 ]
end
```

Comment: How about `numel(vector)>=6`? That returns `true` iff `vector` has at least 6 elements

Comment: I'm not understanding the condition here. What does `vector(6)` mean in the context of this question? If there's a 6th element in `vector`? If `6` is contained in `vector`? `ismember` is not limited to cell arrays.

Comment: `in` checks if an element is contained in a vector, while your code probably wants to check for indices. Could you change your example to `vector = [ 11 12 13 14 15 ]`, this would make clear where you are talking about indices and where about elements of the vector.

Comment: `vector(6)` means: if there's a 6th element in `vector`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- To see if `vector` has an element with **index** `6`: use

  ```
  numel(vector)>=6
  ```

  This returns `true` iff `vector` has at least `6` elements.
- To see if `vector` has some element with **value** `6`: use

  ```
  any(vector==6)
  ```

  or

  ```
  ismember(6, vector)
  ```

  Either of these return `true` iff `vector` has an element equal to `6`.